# php - regex exact matches

Tags: php, regex

I have the following strings:

```
Falchion-Case
P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
```

I also have the following URLS which are inside a text file:

```
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/115714004/FALCHION-CASE-KEY-
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/115716486/FALCHION-CASE-
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2018/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
```

I'm looping through each line in the text file and checking if the string is found inside the URL:

```
// Read from file
if (stristr($item, "stattrak") === FALSE) {
    $lines = file(public_path().'/csgoanalyst.txt');
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
        if(preg_match('/(?<!\-)('.$item.')\b/',$line) != false) {  // case insensitive
            echo $line;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when `$item = P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN` however when `$item = Falchion-Case` It matches on both URL's when only the second: `http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/115716486/FALCHION-CASE-` is valid

Comment: use the `$` end of line

Comment: Well, the `$item` appears in both URLs. Does the `-` character have any extra meaning?

Comment: @Bart Friederichs no `-` is just part of the string, it's also on around another 3000 strings I'm processing and not on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your regx to match the end of the line, assuming the line ends

```
 '/('.$item.')$/'
```

This would match

```
  http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/115714004/FALCHION-CASE-KEY- <<end of line
```

Basically do an ends with type match, you can do this too

```
   '/('.$item.')\-?$/'
```

to optionally match an ending hyphen

Comment: if you add the `-` to the end of item it will

Comment: `$item` wouldn't include the trailing `-`

Comment: well you dont want an exact match then do you, you could also add `-?` to the end the `?` means optional

Comment: Unfortunately that still matches: `http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/115714004/FALCHION-CASE-KEY-`

I'm looking for:
`http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/115714004/FALCHION-CASE-`

Comment: I doubt that matches unless you have the wrong `$item` in there, https://regex101.com/r/xC6kZ0/2 vs https://regex101.com/r/xC6kZ0/3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a negative lookahead to negate that unwanted case:

```
preg_match('/(?<!-)'. preg_quote($item) .'(?!-\w)/i', $line);
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find any match with this